# Can maven lesscss plugin output to the same directory?

Tags: maven, less

I am trying to use maven plugin lesscss to compile less to css.

Can this plugin compile less to css and then put css to the same directory with less?
(My less files is in different directory)

like:

```
   styles/something/something.less
   styles/otherthing/otherthing.less
```

after compile, should be like this:

```
   styles/something/something.css
   styles/otherthing/otherthing.less
```

Or anyother suggestion?   Thx for your help: )

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but won't be it be confusing?

From the [documentation](https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/less</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/css</outputDirectory>
         ...
    </configuration>
    ...
</plugin>
```

You can set `<outputDirectory>` suitably to achieve what you want.

Comment: Will this compile all the css file into same directory? Cause I put the less file into different folders. And I want to compile the css file into the same directory with my less file.

Answer (score 0):

@Tyler.z.yang you would do something like this:

```
 <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/less</outputDirectory>
```

Comment: But all my less file is in different directory. If I do that, that means I will put all these css files in the same directory.